# manipulating result of css mix-blend-mode

Tags: css, blending

I am using mix-blend-mode to flip the colors of an image based on the background.
So far so good, but if the background has a color rather than a gray or black/white. The result gets colorful.
I know this is how mix-blend-mode: difference works.

But I want to grayscale the effect.
Unfortunatly the filer is applied before the blending.
Is there any way to manipulate the result?

Expected Result would be that the teeth are not colored but inverted in luminacity.

I created another pen:
http://codepen.io/Type-Style/pen/bVMZZL
you can drag the devil here.
It works fine on black and white

**But against colored backgrounds I am unable to grayscale the devil itself after the blending is calculated.**

```css
.bg, .front {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px; height: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #9f9 50%, #090 50%);
}
.front {
   margin-top: -284px;
  background: center no-repeat  url(http://www.broken-links.com/tests/images/faces.svg#devil-view); 
  background-size: 80% 80%;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
<div class="front"></div>
```

Comment: why not apply the greyscale to the child and blend the parent of the image element instead?

Comment: I believe I tried that too at codepen. Got the same result.  
http://codepen.io/Type-Style/pen/XmYrJp

Comment: Anyway, I suggest you don't use this to make images appear to look like negatives.  What exactly do you need this for.  You could use canvases or have a server do it and support all browsers at the same time.

Comment: I know, but I do want it dynamic. As you can see the object is moveable.
That causes a lot of problems. Is there a way to detect the pixel below an element with canvas?

Comment: Sorry fo the late answer, but i believe you can use svgs and sgv filters instead.  You have much more control over the order that the filters are applied.  http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_filters_intro.asp

Comment: No need to apologize. I'll dig into that.But it would be nice if it could be done in css alone, or maybe with a small amount of javascript.

Comment: good luck! be sure to write down how you did it once you figure it out.  I'm curious to know how :)